# Scrollable UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

It might be repeating question. Anyway, I'm making a ToDo list app. I want to show some memo with very long text, but it is not scrollable. Searched many questions and followed many codes, I think there is a missing thing.

1. checked number of lines to 0
2. UILabel is in UIView in UIScrollView

What did I miss?

[image]
[image]

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var content: UILabel!
    
    var fileName: String!
    var recievedId: String!
    var entryNumber: Int!
    var dataSize: Int!
    var entry: Entry!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
        print("From HVC: " + recievedId)
        
        // parse ID and get filename
        // ref.: https://ssooyn.tistory.com/22
        let s = recievedId.index(recievedId.startIndex, offsetBy: 0)
        let e = recievedId.index(recievedId.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
        let r = s...e
        
        fileName = "entry-" + String(recievedId[r])
        let dataFromFile = DataLoader(fileName: fileName, fileType: ".json").entry
        
        // Find the entry
        for i in 0 ..< dataFromFile.count {
            if dataFromFile[i].id == recievedId {
                entry = dataFromFile[i]
                break
            }
        }
        
        titleLabel.text = entry.title
        dateLabel.text = String(entry.year) + "." + String(entry.month) + "." + String(entry.day)
        content.text = entry.article

    }
}
```

Expecting: Want to be able to scroll the TextView (or UILabel)
I tried: Insert views by code and storyboard (surely, TextView (UILabel) in UIView in UIScrollView).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it with `UILabel`.

Use `UITextView` instead which is designed to be scrollable.
You have to disable editing though and you are good to go.